# How to properly mock a Hibernate Query class

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test a DAO call that creates an Item. For our unit tests, we load test data into an in-memory DB from XML files generated from the development DB. This works fine for calls that get or find data. However, for reasons I won't go into, all of our creates and updates are done through stored procedures, which don't exist in the in-memory test DB. So, a Query.executeUpdate() will always fail. My thought is to mock the Query class. Or more specifically, mock the NativeQueryImpl class. I have tried a variety of mockups but the mocked query does not get used. Here is what I have currently:

```
@Mock
Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider;
@Mock
EntityManager entityManager;
@Mock
SessionImplementor sessionImplementor;
@Mock
NativeQueryImpl<?> nativeQuery;

@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Test
public void testCreateItem() {
    when(entityManagerProvider.get()).thenReturn(entityManager);
    when(entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class)).thenReturn(sessionImplementor);
    when(sessionImplementor.createNativeQuery(any())).thenReturn(nativeQuery);
    when(nativeQuery.executeUpdate()).thenReturn(0);

    final CreateStockItemDTO itemDto = new CreateStockItemDTO();
    itemDto.setRationInd(Boolean.FALSE);

    Item item = dao.createItem(createItemInstance(itemDto));

    assertNotNull(item);
}
```

I must be missing something but I can not see what.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `NativeQueryImpl` (a concrete class) when you could have used the `Query` interface, instead. Interfaces are way easier to mock.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in this case? If you mock everything and you verify that the mock is called then you are not testing anything at all.